# .NET Framework 4.5.2 Setup has failed

Tags: windows-7, .net-framework

The .NET Framework installer crashes (or at least the following failed message pops up) before even starting to install. On a windows 7 machine without SP1 although I've read this shouldn't matter.

I've tried running as administrator, uninstalling all .NET stuff from the control panel, using the .NET repair tool and the cleaner tool. Have tried both web and offline installer. Nothing helps.

Is there anything else I can try? As it seems to crash before installing, maybe there's a way I can manually extract and start the install?

[image]

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   VSSetup
  Problem Signature 01: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 Setup
  Problem Signature 02: 4.5.51209
  Problem Signature 03: 12.0.51209.34209
  Problem Signature 04: 1
  Problem Signature 05: unknown
  Problem Signature 06: None_UI_Interactive_Crash
  Problem Signature 07: 0xc0000005
  Problem Signature 08: 0
  Problem Signature 09: unknown
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

**Update**
Have installed SP1 via windows update, but still getting the error. Slowly going through more windows updates/reboots to see if they fix it.

**Update**
Still no luck. Windows is now stuck indefinitely "checking for updates" and the .NET installer still crashes.

Comment: Have you run `sfc`? [Use the System File Checker tool to repair missing or corrupted system files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/929833)

Comment: Go to `Programs and Features > "Turn Windows features on or off"`.  Are there any `Microsoft .NET` entries there? If so, try enabling them.

Comment: stop WU service, install this update: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3138612 and check again for new updates

Comment: any update on the issue? Does the newer WUCLient update fixes the hang? Can you install all updates and now .net 4.5.2?

Comment: any update on the issue?

Comment: @magicandre1981 sorry for the late response. The update you suggested worked perfectly and allowed windows update to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sp1 matters here. The [download pages](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42642) says it requires the Sp1:

> **Supported Operating System** Windows 7 Service Pack 1

You need to install the Windows 7 Sp1 first, otherwise you can't install .Net Framework 4.5.2

Comment: In my case I believe I had installed SP1 already but more windows updates were needed, although not sure which exactly. As per your [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1057588/net-framework-4-5-2-setup-has-failed?noredirect=1#comment1485535_1057588), I had to install [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3138612](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3138612) to get windows updates to work.

Answer (score -1):

The problems relates with some update of windows. Please uninstall these windows updates:

1. KB2918614
2. KB3000988
3. KB3008627

Step 02:
Restart

Step 03:
Install .NET Framework 4.5.2

Answer (score -1):

I know it's an ancient topic, but decided pop in to share my own experience .. might become useful to someone, who knows .. Well I had the same weird issue - couldn't install the .net framework 4.5.2 and 4.6.1 on a laptop, which was vitally needed to run a piece of communication software for my everyday tasks. 4.5.2 and 4.6.1 both were part of Windows Update .. and there was 3.5 on my computer. Tried everything - ran troubleshooters of any kind, searched for solutions on the forums, downloaded and installed/uninstalled updates and other stuff, tried to find and fix possibly corrupted files, changed permissions and settings in my system, wasted two long days on that .. for nothing! - every attempt to install that bloody MS update failed (shame on Microsoft!!!) Then decided to try the other way - manually download & install the latest 4.7.1 - and guess what .. it installed without any problem at all .. so my humble advice would be - don't break through the closed window(s), if there might be an open door .. :)) Wish you luck!